# Remove checkbox background color on change using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple quiz in which user can answer multiple questions, now when the user checks the box I am adding a class for the background.

Here is jsfiddle:[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/svd794rk/4/)

Here is function

```
    // here we add event handler for newly created checkboxes.
    nextQuestion.find("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function () {

      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

        //add checkbox background when is checked
        $(this).addClass("input-before");

        //uncheck the checkbox if another checkbox is checked
        $('#next').prop("disabled", false);
        $('input.cb').not(this).prop('checked', false, function(){
          //remove the background ...this is not working
          $(this).removeClass("input-before");
        })

      } else {
        $('#next').prop("disabled", true);
        $(this).removeClass("input-before");
      }
    });
```

Now when user check another checkbox the other checkbox is unchecked but the background is still there\

I want to remove the background when Unchecked.

what do I need to change to get this working?

Comment: it's working fine in your fiddle link

Comment: @Utkarsh The blue highlight around the unchecked box is still showing in the fiddle for me. OP, I'd consider changing your approach to this. You can do this entirely in CSS using the [checked selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)

Comment: @Utkarsh there is still a blue background showing, that is my problem

Comment: The code at the moment is quite messy. You are giving styling to the checkbox according to `:checked` property or `"input-before"` class. Try to unify this for now to have both - the tick and the background for the same 'state' and choose if you want this to be a class or a `:checked` state. Avoid mixing both of them.

Comment: @WojciechDynus that is why I needed help, I am stuck

Comment: @WojciechDynus I am giving styling based on the check , because that is what I want when checked to show the blue background, unchecked show a white background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through checkbox to add and remove the background class as given below

```
nextQuestion.find("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function () {
    .....

    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
               if (this.checked) {
                    $(this).addClass("input-before");
               }else{
                     $(this).removeClass("input-before");
               }
    });  

    ......  

});
```

Comment: No problem.. happy to help  :)